# Python script searching for string in textfile and inserting another textfile before match

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm very new to python, and far away from writing my own scripts.
For my work with lilypond I needed a script that parses a text file,
searches for a string and inserts another textfile before the match.
I have been searching quite a lot for this kinda script and I did not find any.

So I ended up combining the snipets I found on here and other sites and came up with this script, which is working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# usage:
# $ python thisfile.py text.txt searchstring insert.txt

import sys

f2 = open(sys.argv[3])
data = f2.read()
f2.close()

with open(sys.argv[1], "r+") as f1:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f1]
    index = 0
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith(sys.argv[2]):
            a.insert(index, data)
            break
        index += 1
    f1.seek(0)
    f1.truncate()
    for line in a:
        f1.write(line + "\n")
```

though I made this working, I'm far away from understanding in detail what is going on there, if it is any good and if not how to make it better.

Comment: I'd recommend visiting [Code Review.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: nice, thank you! I'm brand new here and did not know it exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain what each line does:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# usage:
# $ python thisfile.py text.txt searchstring insert.txt

# this line just imports the sys library used here to read command line arguments
import sys

# This opens the file provided has the 3rd argument.
# By default, it will open the file just for reading.
f2 = open(sys.argv[3])
# This just reads the contents of the file
# and stores them in-memory as `data`
data = f2.read()
# This closes the file.
# Essentially telling the OS that you are done with the file.
# After this, trying to read the file again would raise an error.
f2.close()

# the `with ... as ...:` provides another way of reading a file.
# the file will be automatically closed when the program exits this block (even when an error occurs)
#
# the second parameter "r+" passed to `open`
# tells the OS that you'll need to read and write to this file.
with open(sys.argv[1], "r+") as f1:
    # This is using list comprehension to convert`f1` into a list
    # where every line in f1 will be an element of the list (`for x in f1` or `for line in f1`)
    # additionally, `rstrip()` is also being called for every line
    # this strips all trailling white space from each line (including the new line character)
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f1]

    index = 0
    # this will iterate through every element of `a` (essentially every line of `f1`)
    for item in a:
        # is this line starts with the given pattern
        if item.startswith(sys.argv[2]):
            # insert the data read in the beginning into the current index of `a`
            # this pushes all remaining lines forward
            a.insert(index, data)
            # since the match was found, break out of the for loop
            break
        # at every iteration of the for loop, keep track of the current index
        index += 1

    # this return to the beginning of the file
    # since `a = [x.rstrip() for x in f1]` moved you to the end of file
    f1.seek(0)
    # this clears all the remaining content of `f1`.
    # since we just returned to the beginning, clears the file
    f1.truncate()
    # for every line in `a` (that now includes the data read from `f2`
    for line in a:
        # write it to `f1`, reintroducing the new line character "\n"
        f1.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: **Awesome, much thanks for this one,** this makes it pretty clear to me but also shows the problem of the script. If anything would go wrong with reading in the data from _f1_ or _f2_, _f1.truncate()_ would delete the original content of _f2_, then not being able to (re)write the appropriate content the content would get lost. A much more secure way would be using some kind of temporary file, or at least moving the original content of _f1_ there before calling _truncate()_.

Comment: In [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) there is now a [detailed explanation of the problem](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169324/python-script-searching-for-string-in-textfile-and-inserting-another-textfile-be) and alternative code by [Gareth Rees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/11728/gareth-rees).